# Destroying Unity GameObject when it goes out of camera during runtime

Tags: unity, camera, gameobject

I have this GameObject instanciated in unity -

```
void Start () {     

         GameObject myRoadInstance =
            Instantiate(Resources.Load("car"),
                        new Vector3(5, 5, 5),
                        Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;  

    }
```

On running the game, I want this instance removed when it is no longer visible.

How do I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`OnBecameInvisible`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnBecameInvisible.html) callback for that.

Just implement something like:

```
void OnBecameInvisible(){
    // disable or destroy gameobject
}
```

The method will get called when the object isn't being rendered by any camera anymore. This also includes cameras from the Unity-Editor. So if you're running your game and have the *Game* and the *Scene* view open, `OnBecameInvisible` won't trigger for any object that is still rendered by the *Scene-View* camera.